# MongoDB setup for Rocket.Chat error message

Tags: linux, vps, database, ubuntu-14.04, mongodb

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-rocketchat-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps/#comment-44620) for a Rocket.Chat setup on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installation. After installation of Mongod, it says to setup a replica set and gives the instructions to insert the following at the end of /etc/mongod.conf:

```
replSet=001-rs
```

However, when trying to initialize and create the replica set in the MongoDB shell with:

```
> rs.initiate()
```

I'm greeted with this error message:

```
{
   "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
   "errmsg" : "exception: bad --replSet config string format is: <setname>[/<seedhost1>,<seedhost2>,...]",
   "code" : 13093,
   "ok" : 0
}
```

Am I interpreting this to mean the mongod.conf line should read as something like:

```
replSet <name of set>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

the origin of your problem comes from the mongoDB service not started properly after you change.

It's a bit special under ubuntu...:-)

Create new file :

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
```

and write :

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

now, use with :

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
# OR
sudo systemctl stop mongodb
```

[src](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04)